# Hybris Ant initialize error: Shutting down hybris platform since the system cannot be used without working Spring context

Tags: spring, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to Hybris.
I started my hybris server and when I try to initialize, I get the following error:

```
Error creating Spring application context. Shutting down hybris platform since the system cannot be used without working Spring context...
ERROR [AfterSaveEventPublisher-master] [DeploymentMigrationUtil] Error while migrating deployments of extension core
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The queryCacheRegion Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
```

If I dont do `ant initialize` and directly start my Hybris Server,
I get this error:

```
Solr Core Initialization failure
```

Solr will start but fail to index data of my store.

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks

Comment: can you add more information?  Which version of hybris are you on? Did you use an installer recipe to setup hybris (if so which one?) Can you post your config/localextensions.xml file ? Can you post a bit more of the console log? Are there any exceptions or more detailed errors before the message above?

Comment: Needs way more information. Put the full build log in a gist somewhere or in the question itself. Usually failure to  start because of a failing Spring context means there was a build or deployment error higher up.